# Админка kohana

Tags: mvc, kohana

Делаю сайт на фреймворке кохана, сейчас делаю админку и назрел вопрос: можно использовать модели из фронтенда в админке или надо сделать аналог для админки? не нарушает это MVC модель?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Паттерн MVC ни в коем случае не означает, что модель SuperCoolModel можно использовать только внутри SuperCoolController - это условие выполняется только в решениях для стандартных задач. Модели являются только точками доступа к данным, и использоваться должны именно те модели, которые необходимы для извлечения данных. Более того, принцип don't repeat yourself как раз подразумевает повторное использование кода, в том числе и моделей. Если грамотно строить архитектуру, то вся логика уйдет в модели, что позволит использовать один и тот же функционал в любом месте приложения без повторения логики контроллера.